# How to pass off dynamically generated xml that is referenced to a url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, django

In my Django web application I've got a python script which generates an xml string. I can access this script by the help of Django so that the url `'my_python_script_file/'` reference to the script (I do this so that I can dynamically generate it). My question is then simply, how do I pass this XML off to a variable in my javascript code, so that it would look like something like this?

```
var myXML = magic_function('my_python_script_file');
```

Comment: You're needing to set `myXML` to the absolute path of the XML file?

Comment: No, there isn't any absolute path, because it is generated dynamically, by the input of the user.

Comment: So you want to represent this XML as a string in your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must reference the resulting XML from a URL, I would suggest getting it using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
   response = requests.get(reverse('your_url_name'))
   xml = response.text
   return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'xml': xml})
```

You can inject server-side values from Django into JavaScript like you would any other value, but you would need to do this in a `<script>` tag that is in your template, not in an external reference:

```
# your-template.html

<script type="text/javascript">
    var xml = "{{ xml }}";
</script>
```